# Running a webserver on RPI Pico W - but it never loads!

Tags: pi-pico-w

I have a question about a problem I'm having running webservers.
I've been playing around with running webservers on an RPI Pico W, following the instructions on RPI's website ([link here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/how-to-run-a-webserver-on-raspberry-pi-pico-w/)).

My (well, their) code runs fine in my IDE, and seems to connect the Pi to the internet, giving me an IP address.
But sometimes when I search for that IP address (to access the webpage), it never loads the page. It doesn't say "page not found" or anything - it just stays loading indefinitely.

I've had it working before with the same code, but only from my phone, and not my laptop (using Safari both times).

I've tried clearing the cache and reloading, to no avail.

I've tried an 'asynchronous' version (i.e. using asyncio library) which let me access the webpage from multiple devices, but still only on phones - it wouldn't load on my laptop.

Is there any reason anyone can think of why it wouldn't load?
My first thought is some kind of security system that prevents me from loading potentially insecure sites.

Sorry I can't be more specific as to what the problem is - I'm very new to website stuff!

Comment: Can you ping the IP address of your machine from another machine?   Can you confirm you are trying to reach the website from your LAN and not the wider internet?    If you look in your router, does it show your Pi As connected?

Comment: seems it's a laptop issue - you haven't mentioned what that is, nor how it's connected to the local network (wired/wifi)